# Can anyone suggest better ASSERT method to compare two columns of a single dataframe in pytest?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, testing, pytest

I am using **pytest** for comparing two columns of a dataframe
by using below `assert` method

```
def test_compare():
     np.testing.assert_almost_equal(v['col1'].values, v['col2'].values, decimal=4,verbose=True)
```

but the issue with this `assert_almost_equal()` method is while comparing col1 value i.e. **0.850341028331584** (upto 4 decimal places i.e. **0.8503**) with col2 i.e. **0.850341028331585** (upto 4 decimal places i.e. **0.8503**) it throws an error :

```
   >           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: 
E           Arrays are not almost equal to 4 decimals
E           
E           x and y nan location mismatch:


E            x: array([0.8503, 0.1234, ..., 0.9028, 0.981 , 0.9789])
E            y: array([0.8503, 0.1234, ..., 0.9028, 0.981 , 0.9789])
```

is there any workaround or some other assert functions which compare strictly up to 4 decimal places only instead of round-off.

Comment: You could try the [pandas testing methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html) with relative tolerance instead. It might be more appropriate for a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use assert method which strictly compare data up to certain decimal places use this

```
assert_array_almost_equal(df['col1'],df['col2'], decimal=13, err_msg='',verbose=True)
```

this method work perfectly fine without performing the default round-off

Answer (score 0):

You could try the pandas method [assert_series_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html) with relative tolerance - it seems to work for me:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0.850341028331584,0.850341028331585]])
>>> df
          0         1
0  0.850341  0.850341
>>> df[0][0]
0.850341028331584
>>> df[1][0]
0.850341028331585
>>> pd.testing.assert_series_equal(df[1].rename(0),df[0],check_exact=False, rtol=4)
>>>
```

Unfortunately, you have to rename the first series to have the same name as the second in order for this function to work. There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/moss/issues/17) related to this.

Comment: I am not sure whether this 'rtol'  will work with this assert_series_equal because while I am trying to use it is show 'unexpected argument'

Comment: along with this error 'TypeError: assert_series_equal() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rtol' '

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using  Python 3.8.0 version

Comment: So am I. The more important aspect is the pandas version. Mine is 1.1.0: Type `pip show pandas` to find your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for these situations, where you can control the precision if you wish

```py
assert np.all(np.isclose(v['col1'].values, v['col2'].values))
```